# Recording from GigE video device?

Tags: linux, video, arm, video-processing, gige-sdk

I've been tasked to record from a GigE video device, likely from Pleora. Even Pleora tells me that they don't support video recording in their SDK.

A search on the net doesn't turn up a lot of resources to record from a GigE device... why is this so?

My platform is ARM Ubuntu Linux 12.04LTS. Is there some resource / code examples that can help me regarding this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Surely at some point the driver spits out either an encoded video stream, or some raw frames to display directly. How would it then be different to recording such a video stream from any other class of device?

Comment: From the examples I see image grabbing, just wondering if there are open source examples of how a video recorder in linux can be implemented?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to be considerably more specific about exactly what you want to achieve (which camera API, input and output formats, whether you have frameworks like OpenCV/GStreamer/etc. available, stuff like that) to get a useful answer. I can paraphrase how some software I wrote records video: `while(wait_for_next_frame(cam, &buffer)) { do_time_critical_stuff(); fwrite(output_file, &buffer); total_frames++; }`, but I'm fairly certain that's not what you're asking for ;)